# compile 32bit dylib in 64bit osx

Tags: osx-mavericks, llvm-gcc

I am trying to compile dynamic lib in Mac OS X Mavericks, but when I try to link it, it says:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "operator new(unsigned long, int, char const*, int)", referenced from:
     ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Compile flags I use:

```
Wall -Wextra -m32 -march=pentium4 -arch i386 -fvisibility=hidden
```

tried with

```
-stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++ -lc++
```

not helping.

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Please help!

**EDIT:**

Ok, lack of attention:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

So, figured out that this is only happening when -g flag is present :)

For release build there is no error.

The question that arises is why there is no debug information symbols on MacOS X for libc++ (operator new). Any clues?

Comment: The options `-lstdc++ -lc++` are mutually exclusive.  Drop the `-lstdc++` option.

Comment: Yeah I mean I tried it separately.

Comment: Add the complete Makefile as the information you have supplied is not sufficient.

Comment: https://github.com/borzh/botrix -> CMakeLists.txt